# Undocumented "variables" config section in Symfony 2 AsseticBundle?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, assets, assetic

Taking a loot at [`Configuration.php`](https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) of AsseticBundle you can see the section "variables":

```php
// variables
->fixXmlConfig('variable')
->children()
    ->arrayNode('variables')
        ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
        ->prototype('array')
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

What's the purpose of this section? I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include variables in the path of assets, for instance:

```
{% javascripts "js/scripts_{locale}.min.js" vars=["locale"] %}
    <script src={{ asset_url }}></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

We have set-up a `locale` variable which Assetic will replace with the value of `locale` set in the configuration file, for instance:

```
# app/config/config.yml

# ...
assetic:
    variables:
        locale: [en, fr]
```

This will compile the `js/scripts_en.min.js` and `js/scripts_fr.min.js` files. More information in [this blogpost](http://jmsyst.com/blog/asset-variables-in-assetic) of Johannes Schmitt (the creator of Assetic).

Comment: Dead Link + it doesn't work as described in the answer.